# How to get the count of elements in each unordered HTML list on a page with multiple lists present?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I can count the no of individual elements, particularly `<li>` on a web page that I am trying to **scrape** .

But I want it to count `<li>` elements for each `<ul>` on the page.

This is what I tried to count all `<li>` on a page, a simple one

```
list = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
print(len(list))
```

I have a page with lot of list like below, exactly the same class name, everything same except the text inside `<li>` tags.

```
<ul class="tags">
  <li class="tag"><a rel="tag" class="term" href="/site1">Flight</a></li>
  <li class="tag"><a rel="tag" class="term" href="/site2">Action</a></li>
  <li class="tag"><a rel="tag" class="term" href="/site3">Gravity</a></li> 
</ul>
```

I want to count number of elements inside each  tag on the page.

Comment: Maybe consider [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for that. Selenium is AFAIK more about interacting with the UI and doing assertions, not extracting information from it. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Consider using `find_element_by_xpath` instead of `find_elements_by_tag_name`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: Even if i used xpath how am supposed to get the count for each <ul>?

Comment: You need to identify your `ul` sections, then nest the `li` counts within those.  You haven't shown that attempt, nor the output from the attempt you made.

Comment: To _...count <li> elements for each <ul> on the page..._ you nned to update the question with a bit more of the outerHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.It will first find all `<ul>` tag and then find linked `<li>` tag

```
 elements=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('ul')
    #print(len(elements))
    for ele in elements:
        print(len(ele.find_elements_by_xpath("./li")))
```

Output:

```
2
3
4
```

Comment: You can just swap out the second locator for `li` as a CSS selector and it will work just fine.